# Retrofit-Idle java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method path does not contain {}

Tags: android, json, annotations, retrofit

I am trying to add Retrofit library for json requests to my application.
I am getting a very simple but annoying error.

When i execute this method:

```
 @GET("/Server/ports/{portCode}")
@Headers({
        "Content-Type: application/json",
        "Accept-Language: en"
})
void listArrivalPorts(
        @Path("portCode") String portCode,
        Callback<PGSArrivalPortsResponse> callback
);
```

I get this error:

```
Retrofit-Idle
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method path "/Server/ports/{portCode}" does not contain {portCode}.
    at retrofit.RestMethodInfo.parseParameters(RestMethodInfo.java:320)
    at retrofit.RestMethodInfo.init(RestMethodInfo.java:90)
    at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:202)
    at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.access$300(RestAdapter.java:156)
    at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler$1.obtainResponse(RestAdapter.java:189)
    at retrofit.CallbackRunnable.run(CallbackRunnable.java:38)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
    at retrofit.Platform$Android$2$1.run(Platform.java:132)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

But when i remove the replacement body like this,

```
@GET("/Server/ports/SOMETHING")
@Headers({
        "Content-Type: application/json",
        "Accept-Language: en"
})
void listArrivalPorts(
        Callback<PGSArrivalPortsResponse> callback
);
```

it works fine.

Also if i add the parameter `@Path("portCode") String portCode` i get the same error.

Why does this happen? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Upper-case letters are not supported in path parameters. Use all lowercase, numbers, underscores, and/or hyphens.

I'll fix this in the next release.